# In yargs builder property , type is not working

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create my own command using command property in yargs.
For those i am trying to add customizations like , title of the book(one of the required argument i have considered) should be string.
But when i am trying to add title other than string , it is not throwing any error.Ideally it should.
Please help me where i went wrong.

```
    const { demandOption } = require('yargs')
const yargs = require('yargs')
yargs.command({
    command: 'add',
    describe: 'Add a function',
    builder: {
        title: {
            describe: 'Note Title',
            demandOption: true,
            type:'String'
        }

    },
    handler: function () {
        console.log("Adding a note!!")
    }

})
```

And the result is:

```
PS C:\Users\swath\nodeex\notes-app> node app.js add --title=12345
Adding a note!!
{ _: [ 'add' ], title: 12345, '$0': 'app.js' }
```

Answer (score 0):

change the type to `string`

like this

```
yargs.command({
    command: 'add',
    describe: 'Add a function',
    builder: {
        title: {
            describe: 'Note Title',
            demandOption: true,
            type:'string'           // this one
        }

    },
    handler: function () {
        console.log("Adding a note!!")
    }

})
```

Comment: I have tried chaining type String to string but still it is allowing numbers

Comment: not working. the argument is still taking any type